# in the statement that was created by LINQ , JOIN order has not been considered

Tags: c#, sql, linq, sql-server-2012

in the statement that was created by LINQ , JOIN order has not been considered.

i write a LINQ Query Like This

```
        public IQueryable<SubscribeTotalHistory> Search(int subscribeId, string     fromDate, string toDate)
        {
        var result =
            FindAll().Include(i => i.SubscribeIdentityHistory)
                .Include(i => i.SubscribeMeterHistory)
                .Include(i => i.SubscribeMeterHistory.MeterDefinition)
                .Include(i => i.SubscribeMeterHistory.MeterDefinition1)
                .Include(i => i.SubscribePowerHistory.StandardVoltage)
                .Include(i => i.SubscribeStateHistory)
                .Include(i => i.Subscribe)
                .Include(i => i.SubscribeTariffHistory)
                .Include(i => i.SubscribeTariffHistory.BillingCalculateType)
                .Include(i => i.SubscribeTariffHistory.WorkType)
                .Where(
                    i =>
                    i.SubscribeId == subscribeId && i.Status == AnnounceState.Valid &&
                    ((i.FromDateTime.CompareTo(toDate) <= 0 && i.ToDateTime.CompareTo(fromDate) >= 0) ||
                     (i.FromDateTime.CompareTo(fromDate) <= 0 && i.ToDateTime.CompareTo(toDate) >= 0)));
        return result;

    }
```

and i would like get one T/SQL like this

```
        Select *
    FROM     [billing].[SubscribeTotalHistory] AS [Extent1]
INNER JOIN [billing].[SubscribeIdentityHistory] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[SubscribeIdentityHstryId] = [Extent2].[Id]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [billing].[SubscribeMeterHistory] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent1].[SubscribeMeterHistoryId] = [Extent3].[Id]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [billing].[MeterDefinition] AS [Extent4] ON [Extent3].[MeterDefinitionActiveCode] = [Extent4].[Id]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [billing].[MeterDefinition] AS [Extent5] ON [Extent3].[MeterDefinitionReactiveCode] = [Extent5].[Id]
INNER JOIN [billing].[SubscribePowerHistory] AS [Extent6] ON [Extent1].[SubscribePowerHistoryId] = [Extent6].[Id]
INNER JOIN [global].[StandardVoltage] AS [Extent7] ON [Extent6].[StandardVoltageId] = [Extent7].[Id]
INNER JOIN [billing].[Subscribe] AS [Extent8] ON [Extent1].[SubscribeId] = [Extent8].[Id]
INNER JOIN [billing].[SubscribeStateHistory] AS [Extent9] ON [Extent1].[SubscribeStateHistoryId] = [Extent9].[Id]
INNER JOIN [billing].[SubscribeTariffHistory] AS [Extent10] ON [Extent1].[SubscribeTariefHistoryId] = [Extent10].[Id]

LEFT OUTER JOIN [billing].[WorkType] AS [Extent11] ON [Filter1].[WorkTypeId] = [Extent11].[Id]
.....
```

but i got one query Like this

```
SELECT 
[Filter1].[Id1] AS [Id], 
[Filter1].[AnnounceId1] AS [AnnounceId], 
[Filter1].[AnnounceType] AS [AnnounceType], 
[Filter1].[ExecutiveUnitId] AS [ExecutiveUnitId]
FROM   (SELECT
             [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id1],
          [Extent1].[AnnounceId] AS [AnnounceId1],
         [Extent1].[AnnounceType] AS [AnnounceType],
          [Extent1].[ExecutiveUnitId] AS [ExecutiveUnitId]
FROM     [billing].[SubscribeTotalHistory] AS [Extent1]
INNER JOIN [billing].[SubscribeIdentityHistory] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].    [SubscribeIdentityHstryId] = [Extent2].[Id]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [billing].[SubscribeMeterHistory] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent1].[SubscribeMeterHistoryId] = [Extent3].[Id]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [billing].[MeterDefinition] AS [Extent4] ON [Extent3].[MeterDefinitionActiveCode] = [Extent4].[Id]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [billing].[MeterDefinition] AS [Extent5] ON [Extent3].[MeterDefinitionReactiveCode] = [Extent5].[Id]
INNER JOIN [billing].[SubscribePowerHistory] AS [Extent6] ON [Extent1].[SubscribePowerHistoryId] = [Extent6].[Id]
INNER JOIN [global].[StandardVoltage] AS [Extent7] ON [Extent6].[StandardVoltageId] = [Extent7].[Id]
INNER JOIN [billing].[Subscribe] AS [Extent8] ON [Extent1].[SubscribeId] = [Extent8].[Id]
INNER JOIN [billing].[SubscribeStateHistory] AS [Extent9] ON [Extent1].[SubscribeStateHistoryId] = [Extent9].[Id]
INNER JOIN [billing].[SubscribeTariffHistory] AS [Extent10] ON [Extent1].[SubscribeTariefHistoryId] = [Extent10].[Id]
WHERE 1 =  CAST( [Extent1].[Status] AS int) ) AS [Filter1]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [billing].[WorkType] AS [Extent11] ON [Filter1].[WorkTypeId] = [Extent11].[Id]
```

why one of the JOIN was located out of prancipale Select?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything between () is considered as a derived table, and the last join is on the result of that table. Its perfectly valid, but using common table expressions is more readable. I guess linq don't care about readability :)

The same query using CTE would look something like this, and now the last join looks more "normal".

```
WITH [Filter1] AS (
    SELECT
        [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id1],
        [Extent1].[AnnounceId] AS [AnnounceId1],
        [Extent1].[AnnounceType] AS [AnnounceType],
        [Extent1].[ExecutiveUnitId] AS [ExecutiveUnitId]
    FROM
        [billing].[SubscribeTotalHistory] AS [Extent1]
        INNER JOIN [billing].[SubscribeIdentityHistory] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].    [SubscribeIdentityHstryId] = [Extent2].[Id]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [billing].[SubscribeMeterHistory] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent1].[SubscribeMeterHistoryId] = [Extent3].[Id]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [billing].[MeterDefinition] AS [Extent4] ON [Extent3].[MeterDefinitionActiveCode] = [Extent4].[Id]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [billing].[MeterDefinition] AS [Extent5] ON [Extent3].[MeterDefinitionReactiveCode] = [Extent5].[Id]
        INNER JOIN [billing].[SubscribePowerHistory] AS [Extent6] ON [Extent1].[SubscribePowerHistoryId] = [Extent6].[Id]
        INNER JOIN [global].[StandardVoltage] AS [Extent7] ON [Extent6].[StandardVoltageId] = [Extent7].[Id]
        INNER JOIN [billing].[Subscribe] AS [Extent8] ON [Extent1].[SubscribeId] = [Extent8].[Id]
        INNER JOIN [billing].[SubscribeStateHistory] AS [Extent9] ON [Extent1].[SubscribeStateHistoryId] = [Extent9].[Id]
        INNER JOIN [billing].[SubscribeTariffHistory] AS [Extent10] ON [Extent1].[SubscribeTariefHistoryId] = [Extent10].[Id]
    WHERE 
        1 = CAST( [Extent1].[Status] AS int)
)
SELECT 
    [Filter1].[Id1] AS [Id], 
    [Filter1].[AnnounceId1] AS [AnnounceId], 
    [Filter1].[AnnounceType] AS [AnnounceType], 
    [Filter1].[ExecutiveUnitId] AS [ExecutiveUnitId]
FROM
    [Filter1]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [billing].[WorkType] AS [Extent11] ON [Filter1].[WorkTypeId] = [Extent11].[Id]
```